# How to remove headers which cause NumberFormatException with spark sql and impala/hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive, impala

while reading from impala with urls like and

> jdbc:hive2://impalajdbc.data:25004/;auth=noSasl

and spark sql

```
val rr = sparkSession.sql("SELECT item_id from someTable LIMIT 10")
```

it complains that

> Cannot convert column 1 to long: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For
>   input string: "item_id" [info]    at
>   org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveBaseResultSet.getLong(HiveBaseResultSet.java:374)
>   [info]    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.$anonfun$makeGetter$9(JdbcUtils.scala:435)

I know the culprit is that impala returns headers for the column together with the result.However,it's quite difficult to get rid of that with map or filter on Dataframe/rdd api,because using those operators requires to parse the result first

There are also other options:I can try to change hive config to disable returning headers which is a last resort.

Comment: update : Solved with custom JdbcRdd

Answer (score 0):

Try using `where` clause in your select statement to exclude **`item_id`** header value.

***Sample Query:***

```
val rr = sparkSession.sql("SELECT item_id from someTable where item_id != 'item_id' LIMIT 10")
```